# connection between affine map and differential

Tags: differential-topology

Assume that exists  $T\in\hom\left(\mathbb{R}^{k},\mathbb{R}^{m}\right)$ such that  $\left(Df\right)_{a}=T$ forall $a\in\mathbb{R}^{K}$. Prove that exists $T\in\hom\left(\mathbb{R}^{k},\mathbb{R}^{m}\right)$ such that $f\left(x\right)=Tx+f\left(0\right)$ forall $x\in\mathbb{R}^{k}$.

can anyone give me any clue?
thanks!

Comment: What is your definition of the differential of a function, when it exists?

Comment: $Df$ such that $\underset{x\rightarrow0}{\lim}\frac{f\left(a+x\right)-f\left(a\right)-Dfx}{\left\Vert x\right\Vert _{\mathbb{R}^{k}}}=0$

Comment: And $Df_a(x)$ is by definition a linear map of $x$?

Comment: @Bernard yes it is

Comment: The formula you misses a $o\bigl(\|x\|\bigr)$ term.

Comment: @Bernard what do you mean?

Comment: The  definition of a differentiable map $f$ at the point $x$ of its domain is that there exists a linear  map $\ell$ such that $f(x+h)=f(x)+\ell(h)+o\bigl(\|h\|\bigr)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you have, by hypothesis, that there exists a linear map $T$ such that, for every $a\in\mathbb R^k, Df_a=T$; and what you have to prove is that, there exists another linear map $S$ such that $f=S+f(0)$, right?

So, for the solution take the function $g=f-T$ which has derivative identically zero, that is, for every $a\in\mathbb R^k, D(f-T)_a=0$. By the connectedness of the domain of $f-T$, we get that $f-t$ is constant. Evaluating at $x=0$ we get $(f-T)(0)=f(0)$. Since $f-T$ is constant, we get, for every $x\in\mathbb R^k$, $f(x)=T(x)+f(0)$. So you have to take $S=T$.

Comment: why the derivative is identically zero?

Comment: The linearity of the derivative implies that $D(f-T)_a=Df_a-DT_a$, also we have, by hypothesis, $Df_a=T$, and, since $T$ is linear, for every $a\in\mathbb R^k$, $DT_a=T$. So $D f_a-DT_a= T-T=0$. Better? :)

Comment: yes, thanks. and why $(f-T)(0)=f(0)$?

Comment: Great! Oh, that's because linear functions map $0_k\in\mathbb R^k$ to $0_m\in\mathbb R^m$ ($T(0_k)=T(0\cdot 0_k)=0\cdot T(0_k)=0_m$, here $0$ denotes the escalar $0\in\mathbb R$). So $(f-T)(0_k)=f(0_k)-T(0_k)=f(0_k)-0_m=f(0_k)$.

Comment: Thank you! Its good